# insert query not working python oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I have an oracle of version 11g and python 3 on my system. However when i try to run the certain insert query it won't work. It always throw a not connected exception. I have checked my connection and the select queries are working fine.

My end goal is to register an user in the database and then return its row id.

**What i did?**

```
def db_register_applicant(applicant_name,password,years_of_experience,prefered_technology,skill_set):
    try:
        con=DBConnectivity.create_connection()
        cur=DBConnectivity.create_cursor(con)
        skills=skill_set.split(",")
        db_skills=[]
        applicant_id_db=None
        cur.execute("select skill_name from skills")
        
        for skill_name in cur:
            db_skills.append(skill_name)
            
        final_skills=[]
        for x in skills:
            if x not in db_skills:
                final_skills.append(x)
                
        
        cur.execute("select nvl(max(applicant_id),0) from applicant")
        last_row_id=int(cur.fetchone()[0]) // works till here, if i print this, it prints 7
        
        query="insert into applicant (applicant_id,applicant_name,password,years_of_experience,prefered_technology) values ('%d','%s','%s','%d','%s')"%\
                (last_row_id+1,applicant_name,password,years_of_experience,prefered_technology,skill_set)
        cur.execute(query)
        applicant_id_db=last_row_id+1
        for x in final_skills:
            cur.execute("select nvl(max(skill_id),0) from skills")
            skill_max=int(cur.fetchone()[0])
            print(skill_max)
            query="insert into skills values (skill_id,skill_name) values ('%d','%s')"%\
                (skill_max+1,x)
            cur.execute(query)
        con.commit() 
    finally:
        con.close()
        cur.close()
        return applicant_id_db
```

This function is called from this function:

```
def register():
    try:
        print("Enter the applicant name:")
        name=input()
        print("Enter the password:")
        password=input()
        print("Enter your skill set:")
        skill_set=input()
        print("Enter the number of years of experience:")
        experience=int(input())
        print("Enter prefered technology:")
        prefered_tech=input()
        if check_experience(experience) and check_password(password):
            applicant_id=db_register_applicant(name, password, experience, prefered_tech, skill_set)
            print("Your applicant id is :"+applicant_id)
            
                    
    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry,Some system error occured")
        print(e)
```

**Output**

> Sorry,Some system error occured
>
> not connected

My connection file code:

```
import cx_Oracle
def create_connection():
    return cx_Oracle.Connection('something/something@ip/somethingother')

def create_cursor(con):
    return cx_Oracle.Cursor(con)
```

What is wrong with my code?

**Update**

Changed the finally statement in the `db_register_applicant` and now it doesn't throw any exception but the insert still won't work.

```
finally:
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        return applicant_id_db
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cx_Oracle.connect(...)` instead of `cx_Oracle.Connection(...)`? Try to print out the returned value the `create_connection()` method and it see if it's not None.

Comment: This is correct as well, i am pretty sure. I don't know about connect though @Nurjan

Comment: @Nurjan `<cx_Oracle.Connection to something@ip/somethingother>`

Comment: Is it only about insert queries? When you do select, does the error happen?

Comment: okay, the exception has been removed , you see the finally statement , i have closed connection object before then i am closing the cursor, interchanging their position, exception has been removed but the insert wont reflect the data